# How to create an iterator function

Tags: c++

So my task is to create a function with signature: `list<Person>::iterator SearchPos(list<Person> &Mylist, Person &person)`. Which would later get the appropraite position for the person, in order of birth, to be inserted into the list. Its return type should be an Iterator.
I have tried doing the following :

```
list<Person>::iterator SearchPos(list<Person> &MyList, Person &person)
{
}
int main()
{
    char Dot;
    string Dummy;
    string Name;
    int Day, Month, Year;
    fstream MyFile;                                             
    MyFile.open("Kontakte.txt");
    list<Person> BirthdayList;                                  // Creating list of type Person
    if(MyFile.is_open()) {cout << "File opened successfully." << endl;};
    getline(MyFile, Name, ','); //Get line until "," is reached
    MyFile >> Day >> Dot;
    MyFile >> Month >> Dot;
    MyFile >> Year;
    getline(MyFile, Dummy); //Gets rid of \n char.
    Person P1 (Name, Day, Month, Year);
    SearchPos(&BirthdayList, &P1);
```

but even without the body of `SearchPos()` function I get the error :

`invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__cxx11::list<Person>&' from an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::list<Person>*'|`

**Edit**
Thanks a lot for the help with that error message it would take me embarrasingly long to figure that one out. The answer to my orginal question is as follows

```
list<Person>::iterator SearchPos(list<Person> &MyList, Person &person)
{
    list<Person>::iterator pos;
    //body of the function
    return pos;
}
```

This will make the function return an iterator as wanted by my task.

Comment: why do you use `&BirthdayList` ? Thats a pointer, the function takes a reference

Comment: Same issue for `P1`

Comment: What about the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some getting used to, the compiler error is actually clear. Maybe this will help you to decipher it.

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__cxx11::list&' from an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::list*'|

`std::__cxx11::list<Person>` is actually `list<Person>` in your code. The standard library just adds some namespaces. Maybe if we switch the example to `int`, it is clearer.

```
int SearchPos(int& index){} // let's define a function taking a reference to `int`.
int main() {
    int my_index;
    SearchPos(&my_index);
}
```

would similarly result in

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int*'|

So the problem is that you cannot convert `int*` to `int&`.

1. Why? Well, they are different types, and you cannot convert between them.
2. Where is `int*` coming from? You are getting the type `int*`, since the operator & returns an address to the int, thus a pointer to int (`int*`). (extra, the returned address is a `rvalue`, since it itself does not have an address.)

So either you make sure that the type you are inputting corresponds to the signature of the method:

```
int SearchPos(int* index){}
int main() {
    int my_index;
    SearchPos(&my_index);
}
```

, or, what you should do, since the signature is set, you make sure you pass a reference:

```
int SearchPos(int& index){}
int main() {
    int my_index;
    SearchPos(my_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like this:

```
SearchPos(BirthdayList, P1);
```

As mentioned in the comments you were passing the parameters as pointers when your function was looking for a reference. Using the ampersand (&) returns a pointer to your object. I know it may be confusing and seem like you need to pass in the address since your function accepts a reference but you don't need to do that. Declaring it as a reference in the function parameters is all you need to do.